# Any worked example how to set up an oauth2 authorization server with a login form and a github?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to set up an authorization server using spring boot.

This server should be able to authorize the user using the login / password form and using the github (as example).

I hope the image will help to better understand what I want.

Example login form:

[image: Example login form]

Requirements:

1. The user must be able to log in directly (by entering the **authorization server’s** address in the browser) to the server **using the login / password form**.
2. The user must be able to log in directly to the server **using github authorization**.
3. The client (another application) must be able to authorize the user (get access_token and so on ...) using this authorization server **with form login/password**.
4. The client (another application) must be able to authorize the user using this authorization server **with github login button**.

I was able to complete only the first 3 points from the list of requirements using the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@Configuration
@Import(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.class)
public class SsoApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SsoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Authentication me() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("123")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("123"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); }

}
```

The full code example can be viewed on the [githab](https://github.com/Selectorrr/auth-sample)

As a client to check items 3 and 4, you can use the postman with the settings to obtain a token:

- Grant Type: Authorization Code
- Callback URL: http://localhost:8081/client/login
- Auth URL: http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize
- Access Token URL: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
- Client ID: first-client
- Client Secret: noonewilleverguess
- Scope: user_info
- State: test
- Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth header

[image: postman request configuration]

I failed to implement:

> 4. The client (another application) must be able to authorize the user using this authorization server with github login button.

An error appears to the postman console:

```
Invalid authorization code: 97477114b3ec3c53547d
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well for me.

But I have created my own "OAuth App" in github. Then with your code, I've put in my Github App:

Homepage URL: http://localhost:8080

Authorization callback URL: http://localhost:8080/login

and after giving the button and give permission to the application to identify me with github, I have returned the main

```
...
"authenticated": true,
"principal": {
    "authorities": [
      {
        "authority": "ROLE_USER",
        "attributes": {
          "login": "xxx",
...
```

As you can see your spring app is not the problem, I think is your github configuration.

**EDIT:**

In the Postman console the error disappears if you put the annotation `@EnableOAuth2Sso` in the configuration `SsoApplication`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Import(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.class)
public class SsoApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the error. The problem is that Postman intercepts the wrong code from the github for the authorization server instead of the one needed from the authorization server for the client.

In other words, the problem is in postman. For proper verification, you must use a full-fledged oauth2 client.